# Ember CLI Rails: Creating user model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, ember.js, devise, ember-cli

Ember (0.2.5), Rails (4.2), Ember CLI Rails, Devise, Ember CLI Simple Auth Devise

Action for creating the user model on the 'user/new' controller. Currently the ruby code creates the user in the database however the javascript response is still failing. I haven't been able to find much resources on Ember CLI and Rails with user model  creation. Here are the resources I have been using so far (https://adibsaad.com/blog/setting-up-ember-cli-with-a-rails-back-end-and-token-authentication-authorization) and (http://kbarrett.com/blog/2014/03/24/authentication-with-ember-rails.html).

> POST http://localhost:3000/users 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

```
actions: {
createUser: function() {
  var user = this.store.createRecord('user', {
    name: this.get('name'),
    gradePoints: this.get('gradePoints'),
    gradeUnits: this.get('gradeUnits'),
    email: this.get('email'),
    password: this.get('password')
  });
  var self = this;
  user.save().then(function() {
    self.get('session').authenticate('ember-simple-auth-authenticator:devise', {
      identification: user.get('email'),
      password: user.get('password')
    }).then((function() {
      self.transitionToRoute('dashboard');
    }));
  }, function() {
    alert('Failed to register user.');
  });
 }
}
```

Ruby Code

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)

    binding.pry
    if user.save
      render json: user, status: :created
    else
      respond_with user
    end
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :gradePoints, :gradeUnits, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

end
```

Let me know if I need to provide anything else.

```
  Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-05-25 09:36:54 -0700
  Processing by UsersController#create as JSON
    Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"user@example.com", "name"=>"Arin", "gradePoints"=>217.665, "gradeUnits"=>63, "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
     (0.2ms)  BEGIN
    User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'user@example.com' LIMIT 1
     (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 118ms (Views: 0.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

Comment: Post your request data from browser developers tools (or from rails server logs). Maybe it will help somehow.

Comment: So I've realized, the 422 is the response you only get when validation fails. However I can't seem to access my errors in order to stop save and send back error handling styles. I've tried manipulating json response but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing what 422 response actually meant and what I needed to pass back I concluded on sending the json errors back in user_controller.rb and displaying growls for each one.

JS Controller Action:

```
    actions: {
      createUser: function() {
        var user = this.store.createRecord('user', this.get('model'));
        var self = this;
        user.save().then(function() {
          self.get('session').authenticate('simple-auth-authenticator:devise', {
            identification: user.get('email'),
            password: user.get('password')
          }).then((function() {
            self.transitionToRoute('dashboard');
            $.growl.notice({ message: "You have successfully registered." });
          }));
        }, function(response) {
          user.rollback();
          var errors = response.responseJSON.errors;
          errors.forEach(function(error_message){
            $.growl.error({ message: error_message });
          });
        });
      }
    }
```

user_controller.rb

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    respond_to :json

    def create
      @user = User.new(user_params)

      if @user.save
        render json: @user, status: :created
      else
        render json: { errors: @user.errors.full_messages }, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end

    private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :gradePoints, :gradeUnits, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

  end
```

The json response came back was in the following format after using .full_messages provided by rails.

```
{ errors: ["Password can't be blank", "Name can't be blank"] }
```

Hope this helps someone else, and gladly provide more if needed!

Answer (score 0):

My situation in case it helps anyone: I was in the process of converting my purely rails app to rails with an ember frontend. In my case, I was saving an @domain (not an @user like the OP, but same principle applies).

My `domains_controller.rb` had this if/else statement (which was useful in rubyland):

```rb
def create
  @user = current_user
  @domain = current_user.domains.build(app_params)
  @new_domain = Domain.new
  if @domain.save
    flash.now[:notice] = "Domain registered."
  else
    flash[:error] = "There was an error registering the domain. Try again."
  end
  respond_with current_user.domains.create(app_params)
end
```

But these flash notices were not useful in emberland (which handles its error messages in its own way). I was able to `createRecord`s for new domains, but was getting 422 unprocessable entity and would have to refresh the page to reflect the change (new domain). **Once I completely removed the `if/else` statement**, my ember app worked beautifully.